# hvFloat: caption above and note below the object.

Tags: positioning, captions, notes

Using:

```
\hvFloat[%
floatPos=p,%
capWidth=1.3,%
capPos=b,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=l]
{figure}{\includegraphics[width=\textheight, height=0.75\textwidth]{./Figur/resqrbd}}[Table caption]{Figure caption}{fig:resqrbd}
```

Any way I can add a note/description (like tnote in ctable) under the figure and have the caption on top (capPos = t)?

Answer (score 3):

use it this way for notes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
  floatPos=p,
  capWidth=1.3,
  capPos=t,
  rotAngle=90,
  objectPos=l]
{figure}
{\parbox[t]{\textheight}{\centering%
  \includegraphics[width=\textheight, height=0.75\textwidth]{./Figur/resqrbd}\\[5pt]
    \parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\fontsize{8pt}{8.1pt}\selectfont text ... \lipsum\ text}}}
[Table caption]
{Figure caption}
{fig:resqrbd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: able to make the note 0.7\textwidth and centered under the figure? and less spacing between lines (i would like it similar to the tnote in ctable..)

Comment: @latexmp: put the notes in another parbox

Comment: sorry, can't figure out how to put the note in the parbox

Comment: @latexmp: see edited example

Answer (score 2):

You can use a one-column `tabular` environment to wrap the figure (in the first row) and the note (in the second row). A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
floatPos=p,%
capWidth=1.3,%
capPos=t,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=l]
{figure}
{
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textheight, height=0.7\textwidth]{cat}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{0.7\textheight}{\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont\lipsum[1]}}\end{tabular}
}
[Caption in ToC]{Figure caption}{fig:resqrbd}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` was only used to make my example compilable for everyone; do *not* use this option in your actual code.

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo: Works great, but is there a way to make the "note" 0.7\textheight and centered?

Comment: @latexmp: Sure. Use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{0.7\textheight}{\small\lipsum[1]}}` in the second row of the `tabular`. With centered, do you mean the text must be centered or the note centered with regard to the table?

Comment: @Gonzalo: note centered

Comment: @latexmp: then the suggestion in my previous comment will do the job.

Comment: @Gonzalo: easy way to reduce the line spacing in the note?

Comment: @latexmp: `\fontsize{<value>}{<value>}\selectfont`. See edited answer.